# Searching for information about the history of logging

Tags: linux, windows, logging, event-log, syslog

I know that this topic may not exactly belong here, but I´m very desperate...

I´m currently working on my thesis and a part of it is an elaboration about the history of logging. My problem is that information about it is very rare to find. Syslog and Windows-Event-Logs are particularly important, but I need all the information I can get about the history of logging.

So, I´m searching for someone who may know a lot about it or knows good and trustful websites or books about logging and its history.

I would really appreciate your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In early days computer operators mounted your tape and ran your program batch mode.  The commands and errors were logged on the attached operator's console, typically a teletype printing terminal.  With the advent of time-shared operating systems and drum or disk storage, it became possible and necessary to redirect this output to a place where it could be more conveniently retrieved than a pile of paper on the floor.  Logging to a file began.  I don't know whether logging was ever done directly to tape, but I wouldn't be surprised, since tape was cheap and disk was hideously expensive.